# JavaScript error for eval parent.location

Tags: javascript

I am working in Classic ASP. The code I'm working with (not my code) was written a very long time ago, perhaps even long before Firefox and Chrome existed.

Anyways, there is the following JavaScript function:

```
function MM_jumpMenu(targ, selObj, restore) {
    eval(targ + ".location ='" + selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value') + "'");

    if (restore)
    {
        selObj.selectedIndex=0;
    }
}
```

That code has all of a sudden stopped working, and I'm trying to figure out why. In Chrome it is giving me the error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

When I try and run the code, the parameters passed in are as follows:

> **targ** = "parent"
>
> **value on selected index of selObj** = "edit_details.asp?make=ML&n=&r=DA61CHH&c=Hope Ready Mixed Concrete Ltd - CHY LCV's&cus=HOPEAG02&type=&inc=&id=&fw=&cusid=HOPE03"
>
> **restore** = 0

Assume code was written solely for IE 6/7 and we're trying to standardise and make it work for all browsers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will be obvious if you log the string you are trying to eval. Don't use eval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eval` is evil!! Don't use it!

```
window[targ].location = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value');
```

Comment: That won't work, `targ` contains the name of a variable that should be updated. Maybe `window[targ] = ...`

Comment: Right. And it is not even needed in this case.  I take that back :-)

Comment: That worked! Thank you! What on earth was the point of the eval then!

Comment: Well, suppose you didn't know the operator to use. There are alternatives to eval in those cases, like JQuery's globalEval. But that too uses eval internally in some cases, AFAIK.

Comment: @Paddy: `globalEval` is not more or less secure as `eval`. It's the same.

Comment: @FelixKling":Thanks Felix. Somehow I always missed on noting that, and somehow I never had to use the globalEval ever.

Answer (score 1):

You have an unescaped single quote in your url.

```
CHY LCV's&
```

Espace this:

```
CHY LCV\'s&
```

But really, this code is horrible, you should rewrite it if you can.

Answer (score 0):

"value on selected index of selObj  " : it has an apostrophe. You'll need to escape that.

Comment: Nice! can you tell me how please :)

Comment: Can you try Oriol's solution please. That fixes the problem in a better way. Otherwise, You can replace apostrophe with corresponding url encode (&#39;). JS has an escape function, but will not work in this case.